# MySQL UPDATE with random number between 79-80

Tags: mysql

```
UPDATE tableName SET columnName = FLOOR( 79 + RAND( ) *80 );
```

I tried these but not working

Comment: _"it's not working"_ is not a problem description. What is not working? Do you get incorrect results? Or do you get an error message? You have an answer which, I suspect, is incorrect, but who knows? Maybe that guess is right and mine is wrong. Take the [tour] you ignored when you joined, and see [ask]

Comment: Please describe your question in more details.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to achieve the range 79-80, a range of 2 (79 and 80), then 2 is the multiplier.

For example, running with: `select FLOOR( 79 + (RAND( ) * 2) );`, depending upon the run, may give:

[image]

Try this [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MxblkymL) example. Click the `run` button a few times to see the variations of getting 79 or 80.

MySQL's info on the `RAND()` function:

[image]

Documentation [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand).